# Which is your best underestimated (by other users) answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes it happens to receive a lot of votes for a simple answer, ten minutes' work, whereas an excellent or elaborated one earns fewer votes it deserves.

A famous example of the first kind is [David Carlisle's answer to the grandma's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94891/101651).

A recent instance of the second type is [another David's post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378062/101651) which is the cleanest among the answers to that question but not the most upvoted (at the time I wrote this post).

Which is your best answer among the ones which received few votes?

If you are too humble to point out your own answer, you could highlight another user's one.

You could also extend this to questions.

Comment: I like the idea, although I'm too lazy to search for an answer :)

Comment: @TeXnician just post an example, you can update your answer later, if you find a best one :):):)

Comment: just pick any answer of mine where an answer of egreg has a green tick

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is only the embarrassment of choice, then! LOL

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256627/nested-acronyms-with-acro-and-mouse-over/266417#266417 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318670/generating-ukulele-chord-diagrams/325536#325536 where each time the answer included work on and an update to my package…

Comment: @clemens you could transform your comment into an answer :)

Comment: Now is this a call to upvote the underrated answers by user John or Jane Doe? ;-) I think a lot of answers are underrated and show the lack of appreciation

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why not? It may be a way to reward them, even if a bit late... :):):)

Comment: all ConText answers from Aditya

Comment: Sometimes I have a feeling, that egreg's answers get more upvotes just because he is egreg, not because they are noticeably better.

Comment: @Skillmon David Carlisle will be very happy of your comment :)

Comment: @Skillmon: Cough.... and some other posts as well just because they are written by ... (fill in the names yourself ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this [Numbering many equations...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278712/numbering-many-equations-automatically-plus-allowing-to-add-new-equations) came to my mine. Although you didn't provide an answer but you've written the package. LOL

Comment: It's been a few months now, and some of the highlighted answers have gotten a few new upvotes, but most of the activity has taken place here on meta. As a reminder for future visitors, "reward existing answer" is an officially sanctioned reason for starting [bounties](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: Of course, but you can't start a bounty to reward your own answer :):):)

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to add this answer of @moewe:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170321/36296

This basically creates a completely new style and for all the work it did not even get accepted by the OP and only a single upvote :( There are many similar answers of her/him but I guess since most bibliography questions are about tweaking something to fit some very particular style, they are often not widely applicable and therefore terribly underrated - but maybe it's just the missing ducks.

Comment: Excellent example! Posts with BibLaTeX are among the most complex and underestimated ones.

Comment: Ahh, that's where all the upvotes came from. I expected some elaborate voting fraud scheme, ... Yes, `biblatex` answers are sometimes 'underrated' especially when it comes to things that are lots of work, while sometimes very easy answers get lots of upvotes (of course they are also easier to understand). But I guess you know that

Comment: @moewe Not to forget all your work on goLaTeX where you can't get any upvotes. Once again, a big Thank You.

Comment: @cfr The question explicitly states "... you could highlight another user's one." So I think it answers the question and works really well -- +27 votes for moewe!

Comment: @samcarter Oops. Missed that. You're quite right. Sorry. (I still thought your answer was a perfectly good one, regardless.)

Comment: Maybe we need somebody to ask for a bibliography style which incorporates ducks, just so moewe can answer and make up the missing reputation?

Comment: @cfr I wonder what the bib style for the `Donald Duck Adventures` is :) We should ask this next January: https://www.daysoftheyear.com/days/rubber-duckie-day/

Comment: In my view, `biblatex` questions on this site are too dependent on whether or not @moewe looks at them and answers them. I have a number of `biblatex` questions here that wouldn't have a solution if @moewe wasn't here.

Comment: @Sverre You're definitely right, we have few BibLaTeX experts here!

Answer (score 14):

Maybe I have sentimental attachment to this answer of mine, which was one of the first few questions I answered.  It was very instructive on how the reputation system actually works.  The answer took quite a bit of sleuthing, but received only four votes. At the same time  answering simpler questions that could be answered simply by reading package documentation could gain many more votes.  And then of course there's the [tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz) automatic bonus. :)

- [lineno and syntax package incompatibilities](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7996/2693)

I also answer a lot of [linguistics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) questions which since few people use those specialized packages tend not to get many votes. I do, however, get many thanks from random people at linguistics conferences, which makes up for it.

Comment: Thank you for your contribute! Also for mentioning the linguistics posts.

Comment: It might help to add an image https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKHKs.png

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I notice that many of all of our older answers don't include images, but now we almost always include them. But I think the reality is that the more specialized the question, the fewer views it gets and also it's harder for non-specialists to decide whether it's a good answer or not so people just tend not to upvote them. (Of course I don't need any more votes).

Answer (score 11):

I think one of mine which required a good slice of work but got only 1 upvote is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365756/117050) to the question "Justifying ('ragged right/left, center') all the tables in a document". There might be others but I think only 1 upvote is a bit harsh even if this answer is not applicable for anyone else.

Comment: The single upvote is not even by the OP although this seems exactly like the solution he/she was looking for - so sad :(

Comment: @samcarter how do you know who placed votes? I can only see the balance but not who did vote... When does one get this privilege?

Comment: @Skilmon One never gains this privilege, the only votes you will ever see are your own. Let's just say that in this specific case I coincidentally know who voted :)

Comment: @samcarter ok, that explains everything! And I thought you were a hax0r...

Comment: @Skillmon: Now there are 3 votes as of now ;-) And you can look on the number of votes somebody has cast on his/her profile -- of course not for which posts the votes were cast

Comment: Especially this is the case of careless users: Coming, requesting an answer and never responding/appreciating :-(

Comment: You too can share the special powers by visiting the OP's profile: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/122478/alexey-orlov?tab=topactivity ;) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWfF.png :(

Answer (score 10):

This one.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Who's ROLF? Is that your dog?

Comment: I've laughed so hard. Love wild thoughts :)

Comment: @cfr How many upvotes will it take until you edit your answer to "Not this one."?

Comment: @samcarter `v` is neither a constant nor an independent variable. At time `t`, `v_t` depends on `v_{t,a} \forall a \in \{my answers \mid a \neq this one\}`.

Comment: Some people are just more courageous than others (+ > 1).

Comment: @touhami: One could interpret posting such an 'answer' as infamy as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you mean as an attempt to achieve infamy? Not sure how posting an answer could itself be interpreted as infamy. Desire for infamy? Aspiring to infamy?

Comment: It's very funny but @ChristianHupfer is right, this is not an answer to my question, I'm flagging it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I cannot honestly see that it is not an answer to your question. You did not specify answers had to be on the main site. Moreover, none of the other answers will be answers to your question in cases where other users later vote up the answers to which they refer. So you will have to flag all those also, if you are to be fair about things.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't have any under-appreciated answers on the main site: only over-appreciated ones.

Comment: @cfr The other answers where low-voted at the moment they posted their answer here. If you don't have under-appreciated answer, you could point out someone else's one.

Comment: @cfr: Secret duck message successfully deployed. `:)`

Comment: @CarLaTeX This answer had ZERO votes when I posted it, so unless the others all had negative scores, it can hardly be excluded on that basis.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Besides, you can hardly deny that the current version will inevitably be under-appreciated!

Comment: @cfr but yours was _not an answer_, the others were _answers_ :):):)

Comment: @PauloCereda <3 ^^

Comment: @CarLaTeX Of course it is an answer. You didn't say it had to be on the main site.

Comment: @cfr But I said _Which is your best answer among the ones which received few votes?_ which presume an _already existing_ answer

Comment: @CarLaTeX An answer which has zero votes is surely one with few votes. One not yet posted has zero votes. You didn't say that answers posted after your question were ineligible. I don't see why the question should not apply to future answers. After all, a later question asking the same thing would be closed as a duplicate, so future answers would not be eligible as answers to either your question or any similar one. (And if you think my answer did not have a serious point, you are mistaken. It's being non-serious was meant entirely seriously.)

Comment: @cfr Too difficult to me!

Answer (score 6):

Two of my answers that I am rather fond of are [Multiple \marginnote commands on the same line in math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment/216037?s=5|0.3198#216037) and [Pgfplots: Placing legends individually to the end of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230464/pgfplots-placing-legends-individually-to-the-end-of-lines/238464?s=13|1.0256#238464), both dealing with how to place text at specific vertical locations without overlapping them.  (I really should go back are redo the first using macros instead of dimen registers.)

Comment: Both excelent answers, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369953/9057 is a typical example of mine for answers that are in a mad challenge with an answer of @egreg (see David's comment to the question above). If egreg answers a question the best you can do is either to not try to answer it too or—if you have already answered it—delete your answer before someone else can see it.

On the other hand https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366576/9057 was a 5 minutes answer (most of the time was needed to make all the links) with too much votes for.

But the answer which made me crazy was https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350024/9057. After getting more than 10 votes for this answer, I've asked myself whats wrong with this world. And I found the answer: Germany will get 12 points never ever again. ;-)

Comment: I'm one of the upvoters of the second one and the third one, hahaha! (To compensate I've just upvoted the first). However, I have an answer that was accepted instead of egreg's one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318959/101651, hence, there's some hope! Thank you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Hey, you've broken my example! ;-)

Comment: Noooooo hahaha!

Comment: You can just leave a comment under @egreg's answers with "Hmm, I wonder if this is possible with xparse" and that will give you some extra time while he is gone to his evil lab singing `o O O o O o m m o O O` or whatever that input syntax is meant to summon.

Comment: Some users are more popular than others, that's the basic scheme

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Some users are more competent than others. BTW: I've no problem with low votes. I find it only strange which of my answers reach high votes. Mostly these are answers that do not cost a lot—perhaps the answers that can be read and used in seconds, sometimes even without the need to understand them.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: If competence would be really appreciated most of us would have more votes... The problem is that an answer (even the first one to a question) will be neglected as soon as the high rep users answer basically in the same way (and although I am a 100k user, I don't belong to the high rep group)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Only 18 users have more reputation than you. The high rep club is very exclusive!

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Yes I know that I am don't belong to the high rep club. Me being beyond 100k is just by accidence

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's more strange my being beyond 11k hahaha!

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Duck-related content pushes the rep, especially in conjunction with TiKZ ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Indeed! 475 points earned with the `tikzduck` answer & question! Hahaha

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Yes. Think about it ... I think, we lost seriousness

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't agree, also prof. Knuth is known for its sense of humour. There is already too much sad things in the world, let's laugh every now and then!

Comment: His sense of humour, sorry for my English!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I am a very serious duck. 

Comment: Sometimes you succeed in giving [a better answer than @egreg’s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299059)! (;-)

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, I managed to find a  [Steven B. Segletes's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331329/101651) that I remembered.

I think it's a simple and very useful way to align text within table cells (a thing particurarly complicated to beginners).

At the moment I'm writing, it earned only 3 upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413018/134574) is exactly the opposite. I just showed OP the utilization of `\hyphenation` and got about 15 upvotes in that day and a couple more a few days later.

It was one of the easiest questions I answered and it is the most upvoted `:P`

Comment: This often happens, people upvotes what it useful, and often the simplest things are the more useful. In your case, I think also the beautiful image helped :):):)

Comment: Makes sense... I just found interesting the fact that 15 people found that useful in one day only. The image, though, is a good explanation :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Just imagine how many votes you would have gotten with a duck in the answer :)

Comment: @samcarter =D I'll put my mummy duck *everywhere* now! Fun fact: The last page of my graduation project (is this the name?) has a [Quero-quero](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Southern_Lapwing.jpg) in it :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Oh, the bood-thirsty-red-eye-bird :)

Comment: @samcarter Exactly! They are beautiful \*-\* [My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHskh.png) :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Unfortunately I cannot read anything, but it looks very nice!

Comment: @samcarter The important part is the quero-quero. The rest is just gibberish to fill up space U_U

Comment: @CarLaTeX: The overrating of some answers (in general) is becoming more and more ridiculous and the underrating of many others is really annoying.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think prof. van Duck will write an article on the topic "voting behavior on TeX.SE", not in the next issue (already in press), but in the following one :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX: That will not change much, I fear.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think there's nothing else I can do...